# How to show all manufacturer attributes in right column of front end in magento

Tags: magento

I have added dfferent manufacturer attribute for dfferent products. i want to show all manufacturer attributes which is added in admin backend in right column of front end.
if anyone knows this, please help me out

Comment: Can you describe little bit more? normally we have one drop-down product attribute for all product and you can select a specific value for each product from the drop down options. And we can set that attribute to show with layered filtration.what is your requirement please explain

Comment: ok.Actually I want to show all the dropdown attributes of manufacture in right section of front end like we are showing all the categories in front end in left or right panel .........like that i want to show all attributes of manufacture in right side of front end.......i hope you can understand now

Comment: So you need to make a drop down product attribute with the name manufacture(or as you wish) and when you will make it there will be option, where you need to select yes , show in layered filtration. After that you need to select option with each product and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

the code is below...please call the xml code in catalog.xml reference right.

```
 <reference name="right">
<block type="core/template" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.manu" template="catalog/product/manu.phtml"/>
.....
</reference >
```

add add file under catalog>product/manu.phtml
the content is below

```
     <?php
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    if(count( $options)>0){
    ?>
        <select>
        <?php 
        foreach($options as $eachval){
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $eachval['value']?>"><?php echo $eachval['label']?></option>
        <?php  } ?>
    </select> 
    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: please tell me why it is not comming or somewhere i have mistaken

Comment: thanks it was comming in front page but showing the dropdown.....but i want to show all attributes in a list not in dropdown